# Counting how many times specific character appears in string - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How one may count how many times specific character appears in string in Kotlin?

From looking at https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/ there is nothing built-in and one needs to write loop every time (or may own extension function), but maybe I missed a better way to achieve this?

Comment: You want to _count_ the number of matches? Now, if _only_ Kotlin had some sort of function or extension method that would let you [count](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/count.html) the number of matching characters…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy with filter {} function

```
val str = "123 123 333"

val countOfSymbol = str
        .filter { it == '3' } // 3 is your specific character
        .length

println(countOfSymbol) // output 5
```

Another approach

```
val countOfSymbol = str.count { it == '3'} // 3 is your specific character
println(countOfSymbol) // output 5
```

From the point of view of saving computer resources, the count decision(second approach) is more correct.